# How to prove that $\operatorname{Var}\left(X_i\right)$ is finite?

Tags: random-variables, variance, concentration-of-measure

Info about $h_w(s,p)$

Assume that $\left(s,p\right)$ is a random vector in $\mathbb{R}^{d_1 + d_2}$, which satisfies  the [$\beta$-modified
logarithmic Sobolev inequality](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1304.1826.pdf) (*Page $10$; Equation $15$*) with constant $C_{\beta, D_{L S_\beta}}$

[image]

$w$ is a weight parameter. It is given  $g(s,p)$ is defined as $E(y|(s,p))$. $y$ is a random variable, which is less than or equal to $1$ so it is evident that $\mathbb{E}(y|(s,p))$ $\leq 1$. So $g(s,p) \leq 1$. It is defined that $z_{i}=y_{i}-g\left(s_{i},p_{i}\right)$

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a class of functions from $\mathbb{R}^{d_1} \times \mathbb{R}^{d_2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^q$ and let $\left(y_i,\left(s_i, p_i\right)\right)$ be iid input-output pair, And $y_{i} \in[-B,B]$. fix $\epsilon, \delta \in[0,1]$

All functions are neural net parameterized functions and hence following the Lipschitz property.
$L_B$ and $L_T$ are Lipschitz  constant.

$$
\mathcal{B}:=\left\{\mathrm{B}_{\boldsymbol{w}} \mid \mathrm{B}: \mathbb{R}^{d_{1}} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{q}, \operatorname{Lip}\left(\mathrm{B}_{\boldsymbol{w}}\right) \leq L_{B} \&\|\boldsymbol{w}\| \leq W_{B}\right\}
$$
$$
\mathcal{T}:=\left\{\mathbf{T}_{\boldsymbol{w}} \mid \mathbf{T}: \mathbb{R}^{d_{2}} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{q}, \operatorname{Lip}\left(\mathbf{T}_{\boldsymbol{w}}\right) \leq L_{T} \&\|\boldsymbol{w}\| \leq W_{T}\right\}
$$
Now consider the following function class of all possible inner-products between the two,
$$
\mathcal{H}:=\left\{h_{\boldsymbol{w}_{b}, \boldsymbol{w}_{t}} = h_w\mid \mathbb{R}^{d_{1}} \times \mathbb{R}^{d_{2}} \ni(s, p) \mapsto h_w(s, p):=\left\langle\mathrm{B}_{\boldsymbol{w}_{b}}(s), \mathbf{T}_{\boldsymbol{w}_{t}}(p)\right\rangle \in \mathbb{R}, \mathrm{B}_{\boldsymbol{w}_{b}} \in \mathcal{B} \& \mathbf{T}_{\boldsymbol{w}_{t}} \in \mathcal{T}\right\}
$$

---

I have this inequality,

$$\mathbb{P}\left(|(h_{w}\left(s_i,p_i\right)-\mathbb{E} h_{w}) z_i| \geq 2B \cdot C_{\beta, D_{L S_\beta}} m(\xi,h_{w} )\right) \leq e^{-\xi}\tag1$$

Assuming, $$X_i = (h_{w}\left(s_i,p_i\right)-\mathbb{E} h_{w}) z_i$$ &
$ 2B \cdot C_{\beta, D_{L S_\beta}} m(\xi,h_{w} ) = t$

So, $$\mathbb{P}\left(|X_i| \geq t\right) \leq e^{-\xi}\tag2$$

How can I prove my *var*($X_i$) is bounded. I want to do this, so that I can apply Chebyshev’s inequality on $X_i$.

Comment: It is not clear which of your numerous variables are random and which are merely parameters. Nevertheless, for any random variable $X$, including random variables with infinite second moments and/or no mean, there is a function $g(y)$ such that $P[|X|\geq g(y)]\leq e^{-y}$ for all $y\in\mathbb{R}$.  You just define $g(y)$ in terms of the CDF of $|X|$. So you may be trying to prove something that is impossible (unless your $m(\cdot)$ function has more structure).

Comment: I suggest you start simplifying the problem, which involves simplifying the notation. For example your subscript $i$ is not doing anything in the problem you formulated, so you can remove it. I also suspect that $2BC_{\beta, D_{l, S_{\beta}}}$ can be coalesced into a single constant $c$, or perhaps just merged into the $m()$ function.

Comment: @Michael I have edited the answer now. Can you please check now.

Comment: What are $s_i$ and $p_i$ ? What is $z_i$ ? The probability is taken to which random variable(s) ? What is its (their) distribution ? Also the expression $\mathbb{E} h_{w}$ makes no sense ($h_w$ is a function, isn't it ?). Please clarify

Comment: I'm sorry but even with that reference the question is not clear : in the expression of $X_i$, there are four variables involved : $w,s_i,p_i$ and $z_i$. If you don't give us information about their distribution (or how exactly they are defined) I don't think it's possible to give an answer

Comment: $(s_i,p_i)$ are vectors, $z_i$ is a bounded random variable! And the expression I am using from this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1304.1826.pdf [Page $36$, Proposition $6.2$]

Comment: @StratosFair I have edited the question.

Comment: What about the distribution of $(s,p)$ though ? Is it Gaussian ? Sub-Gaussian ? Something else ?

Comment: @StratosFair please check the edited question